# How to download a file from an file input stream in Angular 8?

Tags: angular

I get response from service like this {"fileName": "cb752225-cccb-4488-9cfd-f9db37be3df4.xlsx"}.
 How do I download actual data from this input stream? I am using file-saver to for downloading.

Service:

```
`csvExport(id, positions) {
return this.http
  .post(
    `/mc/api/comp/csvExport?setId=${id}`, {"setId" : `${this.positionId}`}, {responseType: 
     blob'}
  )
  .map(
    data => {
      return data;
    },
    error => {
      console.log('Error ', error);
    }
  );
```

}

Positions.ts file

```
exportDataAsCsv() {
this.testPortfolioService.csvExport(this.positionId, this.responsePositionsData).subscribe(data => {
  const fileExtension = '.csv';
  this.downloadFile(data, fileExtension);
});
} 

downloadFile(data, fileExtension) {
const blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/vnd.ms.excel' });
const file = new File([blob], 'luka' + fileExtension, { type: 'application/vnd.ms.excel' });

saveAs(file);
```

}

Comment: it is file name as string you need to send file, is it C# at the backend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this, In your html file use like this

```
<a [href]="fileDownloadUri">Download</a>
```

Here "fileDownloadUri" is the download url of the file

Comment: consider adding the ts-only answer. your answer is html-only.